# How can i load an image with the same name number of for cycle iteration on python?

Tags: python, arrays, image

I have a question
I want to load a few images from a folder into an array . These images are named ( 1.jpg , 2.jpg , 3.jpg ) and want to load corresponding image to the number of the iteration for cycle .

E.i

If this cycle for at iteration 2 I should load 2.jpg image .

Thank you

```
pictures = []

i = 0

for i in range (0,5):
    pictures[i] = load_image ('images/1.jpg') # 1.jpg should be i.jpg
```

As I do ??

Thank

Comment: There's another problem in your code, after you fix this one. You can't do `pictures[0] = …` to an empty list; you'll get an `IndexError`. You probably want `pictures.append(…)` instead. (Also, that `i = 0` is useless, and possibly misleading. You don't need to "declare" variables in advance like C or Java, if that's what you were thinking.)

Answer (score 1):

use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) passing in i through each iteration

```
for i in range(5):
    pictures[i] = load_image('images/{}.jpg'.format(i))


In [1]: for i in range(5):
   ...:     print ('images/{}.jpg'.format(i))
   ...:     
images/0.jpg
images/1.jpg
images/2.jpg
images/3.jpg
images/4.jpg
```

If you want start at `1` use  `range(1,5)`

Comment: Thank! for your explanation :), but i have a query.
If i want to load since 1.jpg image, but let [0] null to fill later, its possible?

I want to do is load images from 1 to 5 in the array, and then at a certain moment load another image at position 0 (photo taken from a webcam)

Comment: not sure I follow, do you want to load it after all the other images?